# How can I get hidden value by checkbox value from under the same <td> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

I have a table like this:

```
<table id="TempTable">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="1" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="2" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox3"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="3" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

And I want to get the hidden value in the same `td` as the checked checkbox.

I tried this:

```
$("#TempTable tr input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
  alert($("#"+this.id).parent("td").child("input:hidden").val());
});
```

Of course, after I get value what I want, I will save it to an Array.

Comment: Why don't you put the value inside your checkbox input ?

Comment: So why doesn't the checkbox have the value?

Comment: you should just be able to `$(this).parent().find("input:hidden").val()` in your `.each()`, but why don't you just put the value on the checkbox itself..?

Comment: `.next()` can be used as its following sibling i.e. `$(this).next("input:hidden").val()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the values are not on the checkbox, it would simplify the code.

But With your code, you would just use next and map.

```js
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var vals = $(":checkbox:checked").map( function(){
        return $(this).next().val();
    }).get();
    console.log(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TempTable">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="1" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="2" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox3"/>
   <input type="hidden" value="3" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

and as I said before putting the values on the checkbox simplify's it

```js
$(":checkbox").on("change", function() {
    var vals = $(":checkbox:checked").map( function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
    console.log(vals);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="TempTable">
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox1" value="1"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox2" value="2"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <input type="checkbox" id="chkbox3" value="3"/>
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").each( function (){
    var value = $(this).parent().find("input:hidden").val();
    // this will return the value of each hidden field
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use siblings and input type hidden to get the value.

```
$("#TempTable tr input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
   $(this).siblings('input[type=hidden]').val()
});
```